# Convert color wavelength to rgb (xcolor)

Tags: color

I have the following color:

`\definecolor{SEviolet}{wave}{377}`

Which is a violet with a wavelength of 377nm.  How do I convert this value to rgb?

The [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package goes over some conversions on `wave` defined colors on section 6.3.12. but I find two main difficulties:

1. I'm not sure if I should do the calculations manually or if there is a *better way* to do it.
2. The equations are defined for conversions of wavelengths over 380 nm, and my color is 377.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To 1.** Yes, there is. We could convert color from `hsb` to `rgb` color model and list color specifications by the `\extractcolorspec` command from the [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package.

**To 2.** Yes, there is a marginal difference in brightness (`hsb`), after conversion, there is a marginal difference in red and blue (`rgb`), please see the first half of the example below.

I enclose an example with wave colors `377`, `380`, `400`, `600` and its preview.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}\bfseries
\foreach \mcolor in {377,380,400,600} {
  \definecolor{SEviolet}{wave}{\mcolor}
  \colorlet{malviolet}[rgb]{SEviolet}% from hsb->rgb
  \color{SEviolet} Hello World!\par
  \extractcolorspec{SEviolet}{\malcolor}
  Color specification \mcolor\ (hsb): \malcolor\par
  \extractcolorspec{malviolet}{\malcolor}
  Color specification \mcolor\ (rgb): \malcolor\par\medskip
  }% End of \foreach...
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]