# Creating a rainbow color macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I'm trying to draw a picture in tikz whose code is generated by another computer program.  The program outputs hundreds of numbers in between 0 and 100, and I'd like to color objects in the picture on a spectrum according to the numbers.

For instance, suppose the spectrum I choose is red-orange-yellow-green-blue-violet.  Then I would want to define a macro that has one input (a number between 0 and 100) and gives a color according to the following rules:

0=red

20=orange

40=yellow

60=green

80=blue

100=violet

Any number in between would be an appropriate mix.  For example, 5 would be mostly red with a little bit of orange.  55 would be mostly green with a little bit of yellow.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you coloring? Are you plotting or using shadings of random objects? How do you get the data? This still in *do-it-for-me* I'm afraid.

Comment: @percusse: I'm coloring nodes and paths between nodes.  Suppose the computer gives me the number x.  Then I can use something like blue!x!white to get a spectrum from blue to white depending on the color.  However, there isn't enough variation in the picture if every color is just a mixture of white and blue.  I'd like to be able to access a larger spectrum of color with just one number.  Does that help?

Comment: This is more a question about `xcolor`.  Look at its support for the HSB colour model.  What you describe is essentially how the "hue" parameter works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nested use of `\ifnum` to define a color via `\colorlet` does the job:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\colorlet{MyColor}{black}%
\newcommand{\MixValue}{0}
\newcommand*{\SetColor}[1]{%
    \ifnum#1<21
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MixValue}{100*#1/20}%
        \colorlet{MyColor}{orange!\MixValue!red}%
    \else
        \ifnum#1<41
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MixValue}{100*(#1-20)/20}%
            \colorlet{MyColor}{yellow!\MixValue!orange}%
        \else
            \ifnum#1<61
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MixValue}{100*(#1-40)/20}%
                \colorlet{MyColor}{green!\MixValue!yellow}%
            \else
                \ifnum#1<81
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MixValue}{100*(#1-60)/20}%
                    \colorlet{MyColor}{blue!\MixValue!green}%
                \else
                    \ifnum#1<101
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MixValue}{100*(#1-80)/20}%
                        \colorlet{MyColor}{violet!\MixValue!blue}%
                    \else
                    \fi%
                \fi%
           \fi%
       \fi%
    \fi%
}%

\newcommand*{\ShowInAppropriateColor}[1]{%
    \SetColor{#1}%
    \textcolor{MyColor}{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\foreach \x in {0,...,100} {%
    \ShowInAppropriateColor{\x}
}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 44):

You can do this more simply using the `wave` colour model:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\foreach \x in {300,320,...,900} {\textcolor[wave]{\x}{\x}\ }
\end{document}
```

[image: a spectrum of coloured letters]

According to [the xcolor manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), the argument, λ, is supposed to be a visible-light wavelength, given in nanometers (nm), so that λ ∈ [380, 780]. As my example shows, "invisible" wavelengths are shown as black.

Comment: Holy moly! That was simple and elegant.

Comment: What do the `wave` values represent in the model?

Comment: @Thruston: Thank you.  This is wonderful and just what I'm looking for.  However, I can't seem to implement the wave model to color a node of a tikz picture.  I've tried \node[fill=\color[wave]{500}] at (0,0){}; along with about 10 other options along these lines.  I've also tried defining a new color with \xdefinecolor{new}{wave}{500} and then filling with "new" but this too doesn't work (and many of its variations).  How can I implement the wave color model to color a node of a tikz picture?

Comment: By the way, I'm able to use rgb and cmyk to color nodes either by defining a new color or using something like fill={rgb:red,.1;green,.8;blue,0} in the options for coloring the node.  But for some reason the wave color model won't work in tikz like rgb or cmyk.

Comment: And even more confusing is the fact that I can define a color "new" using wave, and then use it in text (something like \textcolor{new}{hello}) and it works just fine.  However, once I try to use the color "new" to fill a node, I get an "unsupported color model 'hsb'" error, and the node is colored black.

Comment: I apologize for so many comments, but I'm learning as I go.  It seems this has something to do with the document class, as when I use \documentclass[xcolor={rgb}]{beamer}, everything works fine.  Can you provide any clarity here, and maybe a solution to make this work in \documentclass{article}?

Comment: @Werner `wave` = "wavelength of light" apparently - I get lost reading the xcolor manual...

Comment: @Jared: For use with `article.cls,` see my answer below. Also about the TikZ error that it cannot use `hsb`. Again, defining a color with the`wave` color space, could be done with something like `\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb:wave}{480}`.

Comment: `tikz` loades xcolor, so you can force rgb color model default by either loading `[rgb]{xcolor}` before loading `tikz` or if you are using a documentclass that loads tikz like `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` put `\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}` on the very top of your preamble. But the `rgb:wave` solution by sgmoye is much nicer more straightforward.

Answer (score 20):

Here is an approach that, for a couple of reasons, is interesting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\makemycolor}[2]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hue}{(#1/100)^1.715*0.8}%
    \definecolor{myhsbcolor}{hsb}{\hue,1,1}%
    \textcolor{myhsbcolor}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \k in {0,1,...,100}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\hue}{(\k/100)^1.715*0.79}
        \definecolor{mycolor}{rgb:hsb}{\hue,1,1}
        \node[color=mycolor] () at (\k/10,0) {$\bullet$};
    }%
    \foreach \f in {0,1,...,10}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\num}{\f*10}
        \node () at (\f,-.5) {\num};
    }
    \foreach \g/\h in {0/Red,2/Orange,4/Yellow,6/Green,8/Blue,10/Purple}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\num}{\g*10}
        \node at (\g,-1) {\makemycolor{\num}{\h}};
    }%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Better sample]

First, this uses the `hsb` (hue-saturation-brightness) model, as Thruston suggests.

Second: Normally, `TikZ` cannot use the `hsb` model. That problem is solved by specifying `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}` which causes `xcolor.sty` to convert all colors from whatever color space to the `rgb` color space which `TikZ` **can** use. You could also say `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` if you were having this printed -- `TikZ` also understands `cmyk`. Also note that you could say `\usepackage{xcolor}` but define the color with `\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb:hsb}{\hue,1,1}` or `\definecolor{mycolor}{cmyk:hsb}{\hue,1,1}` -- again this converts hsb to rgb or cmyk, but on an individual basis.

**Note that `xcolor.sty` must be loaded *BEFORE* `tikz.sty`.**

Third, the function that actually sets up what the hue is

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hue}{(\k/100)^1.715*0.8}
```

can be varied at will to get a better spread of colors. The `0.8` determines the ending color, so you can adjust it a little up or down to fine-tune the shade of purple at the end of the spectrum.

So, for a macro that could be called for a specific color, you could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\makemycolor}[2]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hue}{(#1/100)^1.715*0.79}%
    \definecolor{myhsbcolor}{hsb}{\hue,1,1}%
    \textcolor{myhsbcolor}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\makemycolor{0}{Red}
\makemycolor{40}{Yellow}
\makemycolor{55}{Green with a touch of yellow}
\makemycolor{100}{Purple}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample colors]

As an aside, you can also specify `\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}` in the preamble to get this:

[image]

Not sure of the practical use of this, but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple solution to make a HSB shading with `xcolor`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
  \colorlet{color min hsb}[hsb]{red}
  \colorlet{color max hsb}[hsb]{magenta}
  \foreach \pos in {0,...,100}{
    \colorlet{my color hsb}[rgb]{color max hsb!\pos!color min hsb}
    \fill[fill=my color hsb,draw=white] (\pos,1) rectangle +(1mm,5mm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mixing [Paul Gaborit's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230439/38080) with `xcolor` wave model and [color conversions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172341/convert-color-wavelength-to-rgb-xcolor):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
  \foreach \wav in {380, 384,...,780}{
      \definecolor{tmpcolor}{wave}{\wav}
      \colorlet{mycolor}[rgb]{tmpcolor}
      \fill[fill=mycolor,draw=white] (\wav,1) rectangle +(4mm,15mm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rainbow]