# Make a rainbow line

Tags: color, titles, rules, covers, gradient

I found a template for a title page:
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/vertical-line-title-page

There's a piece of code that draws a vertical line:

```
\rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
```

I've worked out that I can add color in the following way:

```
\textcolor{mycolor}{\rule{3pt}{\textheight}}
```

However, this makes the line only single color. The title of my book is "The Rainbow Book", so I'd like the line to be... well - a rainbow. Is there a simple way e.g. to define my color as a gradient or so ?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230265/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No gradient really yet, just a bunch of vertical lines with colors changing from `red` to `violet` in `\foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[named]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {red,orange,yellow,green,blue,violet} {%
\textcolor{\x}{\rule{3pt}{\textheight}}%
}
\end{document}
```

And another version with Ti*k*Z and a vertical shading with `\pgfdeclareverticalshading`, which is taken from the pgf manual (see page 1088 of current manual version). It starts from red to blue but the shading is different, so `shading angle=270` is used in order to rotate the order of the direction, otherwise use `shading angle=90`. If a vertical shading is desired, omit the `shading angle` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[named]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(red); color(35bp)=(yellow);
color(45bp)=(green); color(55bp)=(cyan); color(65bp)=(blue);
color(75bp)=(violet); color(100bp)=(violet)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[shading=rainbow,shading angle=270] (0,0) rectangle (5cm,\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...what about `indigo` (I guess `...,blue,blue!50!violet,violet` would work)?

Comment: @Werner: That works, but in this case the width of the rule is too large, in my opinion. The TikZ version is cleaner, I think. There are of course other solutions as well, with pstricks etc.