# Pgfplots fillbetween and Tikz \shade

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading, fillbetween

I am trying to replace the rainbow in this MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[%
        %decimalsymbol=comma,
        locale=DE,
]{siunitx}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[samples=200, scale=1.15,declare function={
        planck(\x,\T)=(374177152466412/\x^5)/(exp(14387.77/(\x*\T))-1);
    }]
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=3,
    xlabel={$\omega$ [\si{\hertz}]},
    ymin=0,
    ylabel={$\rho (\omega; T)$ [\si{\joule\per\cubic\meter}]},
    ytick=\empty,
    no markers,
    grid=both,
    domain=0.1:3,
    ]
    \addplot+ [forget plot,name path=A] {planck(x,6000)};
    \addplot [forget plot,name path=B,samples=2] {0};
%-------------------------------
%   add shading code here...
%-------------------------------
    \addplot [forget plot,blue] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.4:.47}];
    \addplot [forget plot,green] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.47:.535}];
    \addplot [forget plot,yellow] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.535:.6}];   
    \addplot [forget plot,orange] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.6:.66}];             
    \addplot [forget plot,red] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.66:.72}];

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{3000, 4000, 5000, 6000}
    {
        \addplot {planck(x,#1)};
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$T = #1\,\si{\kelvin}$}
    }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Planck with rainbow]

with the shaded rainbow from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380089) answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[named]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(red); color(35bp)=(yellow);
color(45bp)=(green); color(55bp)=(cyan); color(65bp)=(blue);
color(75bp)=(violet); color(100bp)=(violet)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[shading=rainbow,shading angle=270] (0,0) rectangle (5cm,\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How is it possible to "mix" the tikz and pgfplots code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shading` can be used more or less instead of `fill`, so my answer to your previous question [Planck's blackbody curve with "rainbow" in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501079/plancks-blackbody-curve-with-rainbow-in-tikz/501081?noredirect=1#comment1265541_501081) can be easily modified, you just need

```
\addplot [shading=rainbow, shading angle=90, forget plot, draw=none, domain=5:10] {planck(x,5000)} \closedcycle;
```

instead of what I used there. Modify the `domain` to whatever is correct.

[image]

(By the way, you seem to have made two accounts, I think you can have them merged: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(red); color(35bp)=(yellow);
color(45bp)=(green); color(55bp)=(cyan); color(65bp)=(blue);
color(75bp)=(violet); color(100bp)=(violet)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      samples=100,
      declare function={
        planck(\x,\T)=(\x^3)/((pi^2)*(exp(2000*\x/(\T))-1));
      }]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xlabel={$\omega$ [\si{\hertz}]},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=pi,
        ylabel={$\rho (\omega; T)$ [\si{\joule\per\cubic\meter}]},
        ytick=\empty,
        no markers,
        grid=both,domain=0.1:40,
        style={ultra thick}]

      \addplot [shading=rainbow, shading angle=90, forget plot, draw=none, domain=5:10] {planck(x,5000)} \closedcycle;

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{3000, 4000, 5000}
    {
        \addplot {planck(x,#1)};
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$T = #1 [\si{\kelvin}]$}
    }

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfmath}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


    \usepackage[%
            %decimalsymbol=comma,
            locale=DE,
    ]{siunitx}

    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadings}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}
    {color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(red); color(35bp)=(yellow);
    color(45bp)=(green); color(55bp)=(cyan); color(65bp)=(blue);
    color(75bp)=(violet); color(100bp)=(violet)}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[samples=200, scale=1.15,declare function={
            planck(\x,\T)=(374177152466412/\x^5)/(exp(14387.77/(\x*\T))-1);
        }]
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        xlabel={$\omega$ [\si{\hertz}]},
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={$\rho (\omega; T)$ [\si{\joule\per\cubic\meter}]},
        ytick=\empty,
        no markers,
        grid=both,
        domain=0.1:3,
        ]
        \addplot+ [forget plot,name path=A] {planck(x,6000)};
        \addplot [forget plot,name path=B,samples=2] {0};
    %-------------------------------
    %   add shading code here...
    %-------------------------------
        \addplot [forget plot,shading=rainbow,shading angle=270] 
fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.4:.72}];
     %   \addplot [forget plot,green] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.47:.535}];
    %    \addplot [forget plot,yellow] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.535:.6}];   
    %    \addplot [forget plot,orange] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.6:.66}];             
    %    \addplot [forget plot,red] fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=.66:.72}];

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{3000, 4000, 5000, 6000}
        {
            \addplot {planck(x,#1)};
            \addlegendentryexpanded{$T = #1\,\si{\kelvin}$}
        }
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys!