# Multi-color circular gradient in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, gradient

I'm using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (y) at (0,10);
        \coordinate (x) at (10,0);
        \coordinate (ya) at ($(y) + (0,1.5)$);
        \coordinate (xa) at ($(x) + (1.5,0)$);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) rectangle (x |- y);
            \fill[red] (x) circle (10);
            \fill[orange] (x) circle (8);
            \fill[yellow] (x) circle (6);
            \fill[green] (x) circle (4);
            \fill[green!50!black] (x) circle (2);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-1) -- (ya);
        \draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (xa);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to generate this plot

[image]

How can I replace the colored circular zones with a single gradient that "goes through" the same colors?

Comment: What do you mean by *a single gradient that "goes through" the same colors*?

Comment: A gradient that starts from red, then orange, then yellow, then green, then dark green, i.e., the colors of the colored sections.

Comment: Still not sure I understand. By *gradient*, do you mean that the colors change continually from dark green to red, with smooth transitions instead of the jumps? But otherwise the same picture?

Comment: Something like this coolors.co/gradient-maker/ff0000-ff8000-ffff00-00ff00-008000 (but circular), which replaces the colored sections.

Comment: See the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). Seach for "shading". See in particular section 69 "The Shadings Library".

Comment: See also the posting [Creating a rainbow color macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230227/110998).

Comment: To be honest these references were not really helpful for what I wanted. Rather, I would point people to the section 114 "Shadings" of the pgfmanual. Specifically, Section 114.2.2 "Radial Shadings" has an example that does exactly what I want, as demonstrated by jessexknight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define a custom shading using `\pgfdeclareradialshading` from the **shadings** tikz library. The units `bp` stand for "big points", which, as described [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse28.html), are automatically rescaled to the bounding box of the current path, such that (50bp,50bp) is the centre and (25bp,25bp) and (75bp,75bp) are the corners. That's why the `color`s span `0bp` to `25bp` below, and you can see how the shading can be scaled with the second circle.

(I also removed the `\coordinate`s from your code as they were not directly relevant to the solution.)

#### MWE

```latex
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{gyr}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{%
  color(0bp)=(green!50!black);
  color(6.25bp)=(green);
  color(12.5bp)=(yellow);
  color(18.75bp)=(orange);
  color(25bp)=(red)
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
          \clip (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
          \shade[shading=gyr] (10,0) circle (10);
          \shade[shading=gyr] (0,10) circle (3);
        \end{scope}
      \draw[->,thick] (0,-1) -- (0,11);
      \draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (11,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]

Comment: As an aside, depending on your application, you may consider using custom colours that are more [perceptually uniform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU), such as from the viridis colormaps.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting!

Comment: Just out of interest, is it possible to make some of the transitions less "sharp"? The yellow line and the edge between light and dark green is quite noticeable.

Comment: This is exactly the issue of "perceptual uniformity"! Try instead `\definecolor{viri}{RGB}{68,1,84}\definecolor{virii}{RGB}{59,82,139}\definecolor{viriii}{RGB}{33,145,140}\definecolor{viriv}{RGB}{94,201,98}\definecolor{virv}{RGB}{253,231,37}` and `color(0bp)=(viri);color(6.25bp)=(virii);color(12.5bp)=(viriii);color(18.75bp)=(viriv);color(25bp)=(virv)`. (unfortunately, it seems defining colors [on the fly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24434) doesn't play nice with `pgfdeclareradialshading`.

Comment: ^ update: the "on the fly" mechanism can actually be used in `\pgfdeclareradialshading`, but it is actually just a broken color mixing model, as all scaling is relative to the inputs, not a predefined maximum.

Answer (score 1):

I follow your code with little changes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgflibrary {shadings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (y) at (0,10);
        \coordinate (x) at (10,0);
        \coordinate (ya) at ($(y) + (0,1.5)$);
        \coordinate (xa) at ($(x) + (1.5,0)$);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
        \shade[shading=color wheel] (8,0) circle (8);
    \end{scope}
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-1) -- (ya);
        \draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (xa);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]